# Get_transform not rotating image

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I have been making a game in pyglet for quite a while, and I encountered an error that I cannot fix. I am trying to rotate an image using image.get_transform(rotate=deg), however get the error

```
AssertionError: Only 90 degree rotations are supported.
```

I do not know how to fix this, and the degrees are always between -90 and 90, so I do not see why this is not working. The part of the code that does not work is here:

```
deg=round(game.getAngle(x,y))
print(deg)
self.sprite=self.sprite.get_transform(rotate=deg)
```

the getAngle function is as such:

```
def getAngle(self,x,y):
    return math.degrees(math.atan(y/x))
```

Any help would be appretiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which package you are using, but an alternative might be using rotate from scipy.image

Have a look at the docs [**here**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html#scipy.ndimage.rotate)

The code would essentially boil down to using:

```
from scipy import ndimage
rotated_image = scipy.ndimage.rotate(old_image, angle)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try tommorow. As for the package, I am using the native pyglet get_trasform (I found a documentation online)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me... RuntimeError: invalid rotation plane specified. P.S. the old image is the pyglet.resource.image of the thing